# PLACEHOLDER - Obsidian Digital Garden plus Eleventy Serverless OAuth demo

Tags: app, website

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Stack Overflow user infortion displayed on Obisidian Digital Garden plugin plus Eleventy Serverless generated webpage]

### About

This is a *proof of concept* / "minimal, complete, verifiable example" of adding the Eleventy Serverless plugin to an instance of Obisidian Digital Garden's (ODG) template repo for using a Stack Overflow account to **log in**.

ODG is a community plugin for [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md), a cross-platform note-taking app that uses markdown for note files.

#### License

TBD

#### Download

- Website: https://demo-dg-oauth.netlify.app
- GitHub Repository: https://github.com/rubenrivera/demo-dg-oauth

#### Platform

Web Browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Other web browsers like Brave and Edge might work too.

### Contact

I created this app using several tools.

### Code

- GitHub
- Netlify
- Eleventy
- Node.js
- Nunjucks
- JavaScript
- HTML
- SCSS
- CSS
- SVG

### Highlights

The repository https://github.com/rubenrivera/demo-dg-oauth could be forked, but if you want to do "from scratch", below are the "not so broad" steps:

1. Deploy a site using the **Deploy to Netlify** button from the **Obsidian Digital Garden** community plugin documentation. If you want to run this from anywhwere, grab the site URL.
2. Register the app on stackapps.com. Get the **client ID**, **client secret**, and **key**. For local development/testing, set **localhost** as the OAuth domain.
3. Add the **client id**, **client secret** and **key** from the previous step as environment variables to the site settings on Netlify.
4. Add the Eleventy Serverless plugin to `userSetup.js`
5. Add the authentication files from the Eleventy Serverless OAuth demo (`Netlify/functions/dynamic/index.js`, `Netlify/functions/Utils/*`, `Netlify/functions/auth-before.js` and `Netlify/functions/auth-callback.js`)
6. Add `index.njk` and `secure.njk` from the Eleventy Serverless OAuth demo to `/src/site/`.
7. Edit the files from the previous steps.
8. Edit `.gitignore` and `netlify.toml`.
9. Install the modules required by the Eleventy Serverles  OAuth demo (`cookie`, `simple-outh2` and `node-fetch`). Tip use  `npm ci` instead of `npm install` / `npm i`.
10. To run locally, install `netlify-cli`, then run `netlify link` once to run the serverless functions on Netlify servers. Then run `netlify dev` on the project root directory to build and run a local web hosting server. Wait for the **Netlify CLI** to give a message including the URL to be used, i.e., `http://localhost:8888`.

    - I used Chrome for testing locally. Safari blocks cookies despite setting a Safari profile to allow cookies and tracking. My other Safari profiles with no settings changes related to cookies / privacy work fine when opening the website from the Netlify servers.
11. [Workaround] An error occurs when the Serverless function tries to write the favicon using the ODG `src/site/_includes/layouts/index.njk` / `src/site/_includes/layouts/note.njk` templates for `src/site/index.njk` and `src/site/secure.njk`. Edit `/src/site/_includes/components/pageheader.njk` to add a condition to "favicons" run only on the build phase (not when generating pages by the Serverless functions).
12. [Workaound] An error occurs when the dynamic Serverless function tries to parse markdown notes, including images. Added the parts of `.eleventy.js` and the  property copy `{from: ".cache", to: "tmp/.cache" }` to `netlify/functions/dynamic/index.js

## Issues

- I am having problems testing the dynamic serverless functions locally. I have not found how to reproduce an error thrown by the deployment process to the production run by Netlify with the "basic" local development environment. I think that I might have to use a local user without writing permissions to the local directory `/dist` and use it to `netlify dev`.

## Related

### Other posts from me

- [PLACEHOLDER - Jardín Digital de Rubén](https://stackapps.com/q/10533/105187)
- [PLACEHOLDER: Propose Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange as OAuth provider to demo-eleventy-serverless-oautn](https://stackapps.com/q/10534/105187)

### Other websites that use Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange OAuth

- [RankOverflow: A website to calculate your Stack Overflow reputation rank in all leagues](https://stackapps.com/q/7661/105187)

## Update

1. Moved `index.njk` and `secure.njk` to src/site/dynamic directory.
2. Moved login/logout buttons to a custom component for the header slot.
3. Moved "References" section to a custom component for the `afterContent` slot.
4. Added notes from the Obsidian Digital Garden plugin repository's test vault.
5. Added cookie consent by adapting a few files taken from https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent.

Comment: I just made a post on Stack Overflow Discussions: [How to create a mcve of a Eleventy / Netlify serverless function](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78226753/how-to-create-a-mcve-of-a-eleventy-netlify-serverless-function)